# How to use jquery trigger function?

Tags: jquery, html

I have two functions one `sidefilter` and another is `topfilter`.

### user.js

```
sidefilter();
function sidefilter(){
    $('.sidefilter').unbind("click");
    $('.sidefilter').on("click",function(e){
        var fid=$(this).attr('data-id');
        var filtertype=$(this).attr('data-type');
        var type = $('.view-list').hasClass("active")?"list":"grid";
        $.post(urljs+"user/FilterController/index",{'fid':fid, 'filtertype':filtertype, 'type':type},function(data){
            $("#sidefilter").html(data.view);
            sidefilter();
            topfilter();
        },"json");
        e.preventDefault();
    });
}

topfilter();
function topfilter(){
    $("[name=topfilter]").unbind('change'); 
    $("[name=topfilter]").on("change",function(e){


   **I want to use trigger event here and use of that i want call sidefilter function. This topfilter is drop down input**

        },"json");   
    });
}
```

### courses.php

```
 <select class="select" data-type="topfilter" name="topfilter" id="all-categories">
    <option value="">All</option>
    <option value="1">Beginer</option>
    <option value="2">Intermediate</option>
    <option value="3">Professional</option>
 </select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example of how to use `trigger()` function : [See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aeaa386d/5/)

**JS**

```
$('.sidefilter').click(function(){
    alert('triggered!');
});

$("[name=topfilter]").on("change",function(e){
  $('.sidefilter').trigger('click');
});
```

Hope it helps !

**Docs :** http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Comment: yes its working but that sidefilter function 6 times there in my js but I need it trigger only once. How to do?

Comment: I don't understand what is triggered 6 times, but maybe change the name of class elements to make the code works on a specific class or use an ID ?

Comment: 6 sidefilter function are in my js. All are trigering

Comment: Ok so use an ID to the specific one you want to trigger and change the selector when you call the trigger : example : `$('#sidefilter').trigger('click');`